# Mongoose Populate values and modifying the Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to populate the find results using mongoose. But I am facing an issue.

My data is a list of products and each and every product contains a list of variants. Suppose I have a product named Phone and I have a list of variants named blue, black and green.
What I want to do is to return a complete list of products and a sum of stocks.

An Example of product Object is:

```
{
 "name" : "Phone",
 "details" : "blaah blaah",
 "variants" : [
               ObjectId("5e22d3dabb6cc53debc3a4ae"), 
               ObjectId("5e23629c82aac939fe95c926") 
              ]
}
```

And an example of variant Object is

```
 [
  {
   "name" : "blue",
   "stocks": 14,
   "cost" : 200
  },
  {
   "name" : "black",
   "stocks": 9,
   "cost" : 202
  }
 ]
```

Currently I am doing the following

```
router.get("/fetchProducts", (req, res) => {
    Product.find({}).populate("variants")
        .then(products => {
            res.send(products);
        }).catch(err => {
            res.send(err)
        })
})
```

But I want to add the stocks of all the variants and append it to the result.
Like this

```
{
 "name" : "Phone",
 "details" : "blaah blaah",
 "variants" : [
               {
                "name" : "blue",
                "stocks": 14,
                "cost" : 200
               },
               {
                "name" : "black",
                "stocks": 9,
                "cost" : 202
                } 
              ],
 "stocks": 23
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an aggregation pipeline with a `$reduce` operator but before that you have to populate the documents, you can do that with `$lookup` which is similar to populate.Here is an example with your data. I haven't tested but I hope it works.

```
Product.aggregate([{
     $lookup: {
        from: "variants",
        localField: "variant",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as:"variant"
      }

}, {
        "$addFields": {
            "stocks": {
                "$reduce": {
                    "input": "$variants",
                    "initialValue": 0,
                    "in": { "$add" : ["$$value", "$$this.cost"] }
                }
            }
        }
    }
]).exec(function(err, data) {
    if(err) console.log(err)
    console.log(data)

})
```

Comment: There were some changes that i had to make in your code but it worked just the way I wanted, Thanks a lot

Comment: @Vidhyanshujain can you tell me which changes you did to achieve this ?

Comment: @Vidhyanshujain I am trying the same here in my question without any luck. Can you help me here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78020359/graphql-mongodb-mongoose-populate-field-not-getting-multiple-categories?noredirect=1#comment137567125_78020359