# GraphQL MongoDB Mongoose populate field not getting multiple categories

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, graphql

I am using `GraphQL MongoDB Mongoose` together and I have 2 collections .. `users` and `categories` like below.

`Category.js`

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const categorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    userid: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true,        
    },
    
    
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Category',categorySchema);
```

`

---

`User.js`

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    password:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
    
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User',userSchema);
```

---

`Resolver.js`

```
const User = require('../models/User');
const Category = require('../models/Category');

const resolvers = {
    
    getUsers: async () => {
        try {
            const users = await User.find().populate('categories');            
            return users;
        } catch(err){
            throw new Error(err);            
        }
    },
    

    
};

module.exports = resolvers;
```

As you can see .. I have 2 collections . and inside `Categories` collection.. I am adding my data with `userid` .. everything is working fine .. But I am unable to get `categories` as its keep showing `null` in response.

Here below is my GraphQL query.

```
query{
  getUsers{
    id,
    name
  }
}
```

And here is what I get in response evenif I have data with `userid` same from `users` collection.

```
{
  "data": {
    "getUsers": [
      {
        "id": "65d316bdab8179475bdb0fef",
        "name": "mittul",
        
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

---

UPDATE ..

Getting this response.

```
{
  "data": {
    "getUsers": null
  }
}



 try {
                var resources = {};

            const users = await User.aggregate([{
                    $group : {_id : null, totalPop: { $sum: "$pop" }}
                },{
                    $lookup: {
                        from: "Category", // from collection name
                        localField: "userid",
                        foreignField: "_id",
                        as: "categories"
                    }
                }]);
                console.log(users);
        } catch(err){
            console.log(err);
            throw new Error(err);            
        }
```

I have also tried below code but its giving me `null` in response and nothing in `console.log`.

```
  User.find().populate("categories")
        .then(users => {
            console.log(users);
            //res.send(users);
        }).catch(err => {
                    
            throw new Error(err);            
        });
```

Below are my 2 collections.

[image]

[image]

Can anyone guide me what I am missing here ?

Thanks

Comment: Does each User document contain an `ObjectId` as the value to the `User.categories` property which corresponds to a matching `Category._id`?

Comment: @jQueeny no .. why would we need that ? it should not be .. right ?

Comment: The `populate` method takes an `ObjectId` and uses this to do a `$lookup` into another collection to find a document that has an `_id` value equal to the referenced `ObjectId`. You need to manually add this `Objectid` into the parent document in order for `populate` to work. If there is no `Objectid` given for each `User.categories` how do you expect mongoose to find the referenced `Category` document from the `categories` collection?

Comment: Is there any other way ? @jQueeny without using `populate` ?

Comment: You can write an aggregation query but that will use [`$lookup`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) and you will still need to store an identifier in one of the documents in order to match one document with the other. I don't know how you expect to make the relationship otherwise? MongoDB allows you store one document directly inside another document so that you don't need to `populate`. You should read about [subdocuments](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html).

Comment: ok @jQueeny now I have come up using `aggregate` feature and I have mentioned my code for `aggregate` in my question above .. but now I am getting error saying `Model.aggregate() no longer accepts a callback`.

Comment: @jQueeny I think I am already using subdocuments in my Users Schema.

Comment: Looking at your schema you are using referenced-documents and not sub-documents. This is typically the best pattern to follow. If you change your schema and start using  sub-documents then you don't need `populate` or `aggregate` because the documents will already be part of the parent document. So long as each `User` has an `ObjectId` as the value to each `User.categories` property then `populate` will work just fine and is your best option. However, if you are still stuck then if you post a few sample documents I can write you an aggregation.

Comment: @jQueeny I have updated my `aggregate` code in my question .. but its showing me `null` as result.

Comment: @jQueeny see this answer .. I want to achieve something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/41744323/6829420

Comment: Yes that is a standard aggregate query but can you confirm that each `User.categories` has an `ObjectId` that corresponds to a matching document from the `Categories` collection? Otherwise it won't work.

Comment: How about this foreach - https://stackoverflow.com/a/41744118/6829420

Comment: Can we have a call on Gtalk ? I will show you my screen what I am doing.

Comment: If you just post a sample user document I can provide an answer which I think might help you.

Comment: Ok I am adding 2 screenshots in my question from my MongoDB compass.

Comment: I have added 2 collections in my question @jQueeny

Comment: The user documents do not have a `categories` property like in your schema. Until they do `populate` and `aggregate` will not work.

Comment: I am confused .. What should I do  ?

Comment: Yes .. `categories` i did for `GraphQL` query purpose .. currently which I am trying without any success.

Comment: Actually I do not want categories entries to be added in Users collection. I want it through aggregate or other way to fetch the results.

Comment: See this example .. they also did not add in parent table still they are getting results .. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mongoose-populate-method/

Comment: I think you are missing the point. If you want to insert a categories document into a user document when you perform a query then you will need to manually add an `ObjectId` into each `user.categories` document that corresponds to a matching `category._id`.

Comment: I dont want to insert Categories document into Users. . I am ok with that .. I have a reference of User Id in my categories document .. So if I fetch all users .. I should be able to list out all the categories for the particular user inside that for loop. @jQueeny

Comment: See this .. I want to do something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59804896/mongoose-populate-values-and-modifying-the-object

Comment: OK is see you have the userid in each category document. That will work. I can provide a solution.

Comment: Yea @jQueeny ... I have userid in my categories collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK Guys .. Eventually I have found an answer by updating an aggregate query like below.

```
getUsers: async (req,res) => {

       try {
            const users = await User.aggregate([
                {
                    $match: {
                        _id: { $ne: null } // Filter out documents where _id is null
                    }
                },
                {
                    $lookup: {
                        from: "categories",
                        localField: "_id",
                        foreignField: "userid",
                        as: "categories"
                    }
                },
                {
                    $addFields: {
                        "id": { $toString: "$_id" }, // Convert _id to string and assign it to id
                        "categories": {
                            $map: {
                                input: "$categories",
                                as: "category",
                                in: {
                                    id: { $toString: "$$category._id" }, // Convert _id of category to string and assign it to id
                                    title: "$$category.title"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]);
            return users;
         } catch(err){
            throw new Error("Error retrieving user");            
        }
```

This works in all the scenarios whether I add `id` or not for `users` or `categories` like below.

```
query{
  getUsers{
    
    id,name,email,categories{
      id,
      title
    }
      
  }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple aggregation that will allow you to query the `users` collection. In this example a `$match` is made for the `user.name` property but you can query the `users` for anything you want.

Then you do a `$lookup` to search the `categories` collection for any `Category` that has a `userid` value equal to the `_id` value of the `User` that you found by searching the `users` collection.

The `$set` stage will look at the `categories` array property returned from the `$lookup` and if its an empty array then it will be removed, otherwise it will be set it itself.

```js
const users = await User.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      _id: ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
      name: "mittul"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "categories",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "userid",
      as: "categories"
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "categories": {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $eq: [
              "$categories",
              []
            ]
          },
          then: "$$REMOVE",
          else: "$categories"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

See [HERE](https://mongoplayground.net/p/E1evetxZUlt) for a working example.

Comment: Is it required to use `match` ?

Comment: I removed `match` and i am getting error saying ` "Cannot return null for non-nullable field User.id`

Comment: Because I can have null values .. categories are not mandatory for each user.

Comment: In my terminal .. I am able to see `[]` array but in GraphiQL I am getting error saying `"Cannot return null for non-nullable field User.id.",`

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/ScXWan3JxCA

Comment: We are pretty close here .. When I try something like this .. it doesnt work .. `query{
  getUsers{
    id
    name,categories{
      title
    }
      
  }
}`

Comment: But when I remove `id` then its working .. something like this `query{
  getUsers{
    
    name,categories{
      title
    }
      
  }
}`

Comment: But practically it should work on both the scenarios

Comment: The `$match` is only required if you want to select specific users. If there is no `$match` then it will find all users which is perfectly valid. If you want to remove the empty categories then you can do a conditional `$set` to remove them. I will update.

Comment: ok Seems like I am facing issue when I add `id` field in `query` of GraphQL.

Comment: As soon as I add an `id` field something like `id,name,email,categories {` or `name,email,categories {id,` then its throwing errors.

Comment: I have added a `$match` stage to look for `_id` or `name`.

Comment: Its saying `"MongoServerError: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$set'",`

Comment: What version of mongodb are you using?

Comment: `"mongoose": "^8.1.2",`

Comment: And MongoDB compass version is `Version 1.23.0`

Comment: What version of mongodb? Needs to be greater than 4.2. If you have an older version you can change `$set` to be `$addFields` instead. They do the same thing.

Comment: `{
                    $addFields: {
                    "categories": {
                        $cond: {
                        if: {
                            $eq: [
                            "$categories",
                            []
                            ]
                        },
                        then: "$$REMOVE",
                        else: "$categories"
                        }
                    }
                    }
                }`

Comment: `query{
  getUsers{
    
    name,email,categories {
      id,title
    }
      
  }
}`

Comment: `"message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable field Category.id.",`

Comment: Ok I have upgraded my mongodb from 3.4 to now 4.0 but it still throws me same error.

Comment: Thanks for your support .. I have updated your code a bit and achieve what I wanted. I appreciated your efforts and here is my answer on the same question https://stackoverflow.com/a/78040890/6829420

Comment: @MittulAtTechnoBrave glad you got it working. If you wanted the `_id` to be `id` then a `$project` would have done the trick but looks like you solved it anyway.